# Upgrade On-premise MS Dynamics CRM 2013 to On-Premise MS Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: migration, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a problem when do upgrade from MS Dynamics CRM 2013 to 2015.

When Import Organization Wizard does System Checks, it gets error:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#ActualC__59D49277A86CC312'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.#ActualColumns'. 
The duplicate key value is (SplitString, Data).
```

Other info:

- CRM 2013 SP1 (6.1.3.119);
- SQL 2012 Enterprise SP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen if you made unsupported modification to your CRM database, such as adding custom tables. Delete them first and try your upgrade again.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! Actual cause of the problem was stored in the error message "The duplicate key value is (SplitString, Data)". SplitString was the name of our custom procedure and after deleting it our DB migrate without errors. But in general you were right - that was unsupported customizations in DB.

Answer (score 0):

### Same error while upgrading Microsoft Dynamics CRM

I recently upgrade from **Microsoft Dynamics 365 (CRM 2016 On-Premise)** to **Dynamics 365 Server, v9.0**

I had the same error-message with a different "duplicate key value".
The root-cause of the problem was that I had "duplicate values" in the CRM-Database-Objects.
The following Query lists such duplicates:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(*) Count 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS GROUP BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Of course the duplicates where in my own database-objects (views) that I had created in my own schemas.
Renaming my own objects/views or the columns in the views to make sure the above query doesn't list any results solved my problem.
After the changes in my own objects I was able to do the Upgrade